# c# thread sleep on DataReceived event

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, sleep

I wrote this code on c#

```
public  class SerialClass 
{
    SerialPort s;
    public Serial()
    {
        InitSerialPort();
        s.DataReceived += dataReciver;

    }

    private void dataReciver(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      lock (obj) 
    {
          while (s.BytesToRead >0)
           {
               var line = s.ReadLine();
               if(line=="hello")
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(500);
                   s.WriteLine("hello to you friend");
              }
              else  //......
        }       
           }
    }

}
```

When i got "hello" from the serial I want to answer after 500 milliseconds  "hello to you friend".

I heard so much , don't use sleep on you code..

What is the disadvantage here to use sleep?  If more data will get on serialport so new event will enter to dataReciver because it will be open on secondery thread.

so what is the disadvantage and what is the better/best way to implement it without sleep?

Comment: You could launch delayed tasks every time the event is fired. Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194845(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Because you don't hire and pay a worker to sleep on his job. During those 500 ms, the thread could be doing all kind of useful stuff and you are simply asking it to take a nap. Threads are about the most expensive resource the framework provides, *use* them, don't *waste* them.

Comment: @InBetween so how can I send the command after 500 mili sec. after I get this line?    what this thread suppost to do when it sleep? it thread that open for this event(by the c# doc. )

Comment: @Mat what is diffrent if I use await Task.Delay for sleep?

Comment: `await Task.Delay(500);` seems the obvious choice. Read up in `async-await`.

Comment: @InBetween look on edit , I use lock because I want only 1 thread will be on this reading , so I can't use async-await,

Comment: You do not put a sleep nor an await inside an event handler.

Answer (score 2):

> I use lock because I want only 1 thread will be on this reading

If you've done it right, you shouldn't need the lock.

IMHO, you should avoid the `DataReceived` event altogether. Wrap `SerialPort.BaseStream` in a `StreamReader`, then loop in an async method to read. Regardless, I also would not put the delay, asynchronous or otherwise, in sequence with your reading. You should always be ready to read.

You didn't provide real code, so it's impossible to offer a real code solution, but here's how I'd have written the bit of code you posted:

```
public class Serial
{
    SerialPort s;

    public Serial()
    {
        InitSerialPort();

        // Ignore returned task...constructors shouldn't wait. You could store
        // the task in a class field, to provide a mechanism to observe the
        // receiving state.
        Task task = ReceiveLoopAsync();
    }

    private async Task ReceiveLoopAsync()
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s.BaseStream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s.BaseStream))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                if (line == "hello")
                {
                    // Ignore returned task...we don't really care when it finishes
                    Task task = RespondAsync(writer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task RespondAsync(StreamWriter writer)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        writer.WriteLine("hello to you friend");
    }
}
```

I've left out niceties like exception handling and more robust handling of the tasks. But the above is the basic idea. Note that all receiving is done in a single loop, with no need for cross-thread synchronization.